# Ajax Loader Not Showing In Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, sqlite

I am making one android app in that i have given a ajax loader but it is not showing in that app i my using Sqlite database and phonegap

In JQuery:-

```js
  function callXMLConnection(){
$.mobile.loading('show',{
        text: "Loading...",
                    textVisible: true,
                    theme: "d",
                    textonly: false,
                    html: ""
                    });
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "one.html",
   contentType: "text/xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   data: "",      
   crossDomain:true,
   success: function(xml) {
      $.mobile.loading('hide');
      $(xml).find('outlet').each(function(){
      var outlet_Id = $(this).find('outlet_id').text();                                     // Outlet ID
      var outlet_Title = $(this).find('title').text();                                      //Outlet Title
      db.transaction(function(transaction) {
      transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Envy_Outlet VALUES((SELECT max(id)+1 FROM Envy_Outlet),"'+outlet_Id+'","'+outlet_Title+'")',nullHandler,errorHandler);
      });
      var scripts = "<li><a href='#' onclick='get_Table_List(id);' id='"+outlet_Id+"'>"+outlet_Title+"</a></li>"
          $(".outlet").append(scripts).trigger('create');   
          });   
     return false;          
  }
});
}
```

In HTML5:-

```html
<div data-role="content" >
    <div class="my_body">
          <ul class="outlet" id="outlet_id"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you testing it on an emulator ?

Comment: @T.Baba yup it is not working in emulator

Comment: it will never work :P try it on real device, the emulator don't animation Gif files.

Comment: @T.Baba even in real device also it is not coming nw tell wht i can do

Comment: In that case make sure that the loader.gif exists,,, "Notes: The zip download doesn't contain the icon and loader images, please download the images and drop that into your folder structure." go to http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.images-1.3.2.zip

Comment: @T.Baba i m using default jquery mobile loader

Comment: make sure that u have the Gif files ;)

Comment: @T.Baba kk let me check

Comment: @T.Baba I have the same problem, I see the loader in the Ripple emulator but not on the device...weird

Comment: @T.Baba still i m not getting the ajax loader